# What are the handshaking signals involved when a device connects to the LAN?

Tags: tcp, wifi, lan, handshaking

What are the signals exchanged when my device (phone or laptop) extablish a LAN or wireless connection? Something similar to the 3 way handshake of the tcp?

Answer (score 0):

A possible DHCP exchange and an ARP message in the case of a LAN. Unknown to me in the case of wifi.